# Why are degree zero line bundles on an Abelian Variety translation invariant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am reading about Abelian varieties from Huybrecht's 'Fourier-Mukai Transforms in Algebraic Geometry' and in here $\operatorname{Pic}^0(A)$ is *defined* to be the group of translation invariant line bundles (ie. $\{L \in \operatorname{Pic} A\;|\;t_a^*L \cong L \text{ for all } a \in A\}$ where $t_a: A \to A$ is translation by $a$). In other contexts, this is defined to be the line bundles associated to divisors of degree zero. As such, I expect these to be equivalent notions.

In the usual references (Mumford, Milne) I had trouble finding this fact. Does anyone know of one? Otherwise, is there an easy way to see why this is true?

The two facts which I thought might be useful in proving this are as follows.

1. If $A$ is an abelian variety, $L$ is translation invariant iff $m^*L \cong p^*L \otimes q^*L$ on $A \times A$, where $m$ is multiplication and $p,q$ the projections.
2. If $L$ is translation invariant on $A$, then $H^i(A, L) = 0$ for all $i> 0$.

Beyond this I am not really sure how to go about it. Any reference or help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Apparently degree does not make sense in dimensions higher than 1, so my definition of $\operatorname{Pic}^0(A)$ is not a right definition in general. The Huybrechts book mentioned before proves that (over $\mathbb{C}$) translation invariance of $L$ is equivalent to $c_1(L) = 0$. Perhaps I should correct my definition of $\operatorname{Pic}^0(L)$ to be the connected component of the identity, as suggested by Cranium Clamp in the comments.

Comment: What is the degree of a divisor? As far as I know, it's not a very useful notion for varieties of dimension $\geqslant 2$.  If you define it as the sum of coefficients, then, for example, the degree of a plane conic curve will be 1, while the degree of a pair of lines will be 2. Degree is useful and well-defined for 0-dimensional subschemes, and hence for divisors on curves.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov yeah, degree isn’t quite the right notion here. I’m guessing that by ‘degree 0’, the OP just means $ Pic^0 $ as is usually defined, which is the connected component of the trivial line bundle on $ A $.

Comment: By degree, I was referring to the map $\operatorname{Pic}(X) \cong \operatorname{Cl}(X) \to \mathbb{Z}$, where it is just adding the coefficients. I'm having trouble finding a reference for this being done on anything other than a curve (or $\mathbb{P}^n$) so degree probably isn't the right notion.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, such a canonically defined map does not exist in general.